# Restore PG local database from SQLite DB - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I just switched my whole app's (dev and test) databases to Postgres and got it working well. I did have a ton of information (users, posts, etc) on my local sqlite database that I would love to transfer over to my new PG local database. Is this even possible? Are there any resources y'all can point me to that can give me an idea of how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'taps' gem can do it.  Looks like there is an updated one called 'taps-taps.'

See: https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/easy-database-migration-using-taps